# Why ASP.NET Core convert Persian(or Arabic) text to Character reference (&#xhhhh;) in view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

The source code:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "سلام علیک"; }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" dir="rtl">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It's well rendered in browser but I want the same text in html source (for some search engine optimizer software)

[image: ViewBag problem in Arabic text]

And the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>&#x633;&#x644;&#x627;&#x645; &#x639;&#x644;&#x6CC;&#x6A9;</title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because, by default, the HTML encoding engine will only safelist the basic latin alphabet (because browsers have bugs. So we're trying to protect against unknown problems). The &XXX values you see still render as correctly as you can see in your screen shots, so there's no real harm, aside from the increased page size.

If the increased page size bothers you then you can [customise the encoder](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cross-site-scripting.html) to safe list your own character pages (not language, Unicode doesn't think in terms on language)

To widen the characters treated as safe by the encoder you would insert the following line into the ConfigureServices() method in startup.cs;

`services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>(
  HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[] { UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin,
                                            UnicodeRanges.Arabic }));`

Arabic has quite a few [blocks in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode), so you may need to add more blocks to get the full range you need.

Comment: awesome, I am very thankful that you are considering my problem.

Comment: Very interesting, but is this safe? I mean I only use your proposal as I think about SEO optimization, but should I do other stuff for safety?
Also, if I didn't do this and kept the `view source` as is **encoded**, will it be SEO friendly?

Comment: Love you man...

Answer (score 0):

Even in Blazor Web assembly, I solved this problem by copying the below line inside program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>(HtmlEncoder.Create(allowedRanges: new[ ] { UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, UnicodeRanges.Arabic }));
```

If you are working with server projects or previous version's of core that has startup.cs you can write like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<HtmlEncoder>( HtmlEncoder.Create( allowedRanges: new[ ] { UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, UnicodeRanges.Arabic } ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

For non `ACII` chars, I recommend to use `UTF-8` as the charset. You can add this line into your HTML file (shared layout). in the `<head>` tag.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

And set dir="rtl" and lang="ar", use like  :

```
<p dir="rtl" lang="ar" ">سلام علیک</p>
```

Also You can use  `ViewData["Title"]` instead `ViewBag.Title` it should give same result.

[Character encodings in HTML-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

Comment: I did but it doesn't change the result :|

Comment: @Soren Try also with added dir and lang.

Comment: <p dir="rtl" lang="ar">&#x633;&#x644;&#x627;&#x645; &#x639;&#x644;&#x6CC;&#x6A9;</p>

Comment: Are you try set title withou use ViewBag.Title?  Just use <title dir="rtl" lang="ar">سلام علیک</title>

Comment: yup, without ViewBag everything is alright. but ViewBag changes it.

Comment: even with @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Title) is OK. but I don't want to use Html.Raw in this case.

Comment: I understand , can you Add <html lang="ar"> under "<!DOCTYPE html>" .

Comment: I did, same result :|

Comment: Use  ViewData["Title"]  instead ViewBag.Title. I tested and it working with arabic language.

Comment: I test in 2 different project, unfortunately neither of them doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126590/discussion-between-mww-and-soren).

Answer (score -2):

You have to set the character encoding for the response to be UTF-8 in order to be able to output the non-Unicode characters like Arabic

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I added a picture for disambiguation.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't use web.config for its settings.